# Google Place verification by api

Tags: php, google-places-api

I have used google place api for add location on google map. i have add location successfully.My output is following -

```
{
   "id" : "0ad0070d7c11c58b3ec04088b621df840e1bf0db",
   "reference" : "CkQxAAAA5zX4eD-zw11AXYr655m1YY6Gg4HKyTR5p1OxW2_9Y1iQmEYP125ityHf5T4H7i05K_feYF7Xo4FQ6acTzxdgSBIQwi0bg7iu1sSDWIpYhHT0zhoU2NP_Hfa7Rs_Urdo9g0nHmIJr1VE",
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

But when i search on google map (publicly). its not appear.If verification is needed then please explain to me verification process by api.

Answer (score 1):

The document said:

> New Places will be available immediately in Place Searches initiated
>   by your application, and will enter the moderation queue to be
>   considered for Google Maps. A newly-added Place will not be available
>   to other applications until it has been approved by the moderation
>   process.

Places ADD action is just available only for you until the Google Maps moderator accepts it.
So we can't do anything, and there is nothing other way.